# Maven in java(pom.xml)

Tags: java

I get the following message when i am cloning from git using maven (in eclipse)
Please tell me how to resolve it

1 problem was encountered while building the effective model for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6
[FATAL] Non-readable POM

Comment: Does maven have permission to read the pom?  You can try changing the pom's permissions to 777 very quickly to check this.

Comment: How does one _"clone from git with maven in eclipse"_? Can you explain a bit more on what you are doing?

Comment: I am trying to clone a maven project from git in eclipse

Comment: [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/NoGoalSpecifiedException